# Inject issue (No bean is eligible for injection )

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1

I have an EJB project reacted. I have the below code to invoke service from jars

```
@Resource
private BundleContext context;

private Object getServiceFromContext(Class className) {
    ServiceReference sref = context
            .getServiceReference(className.getName());
    return context.getService(sref);
}

@Produces
public Test getTest() {
    return (Test) getServiceFromContext(Test.class);
}
```

The I use a different java file and use the followig

@Inject
private Test testdata;

The inject shows below warning

No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]

Please advice how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're using javax.enterprise.inject.Produces and not javax.ws.rs.Produces ?

Comment: Yes I am using javax.enterprise.inject.Produces. Also the injection value is null and no object. Please advice.

Comment: I think we really need more info and perhaps code. When you say "the inject shows below warning" I assume it's a warning in your IDE. But with your remark above I have the feeling that the application is starting anyway with no exception but it gives you a null value in your injection point. Is that right?

Comment: yes its correct. I was able to solve this issue by right click. The window showed multiple inject. I selected the non default one and this issue was resolved. Thanks.